Azure Video Indexer upload keeps returning "STORAGE_ACCESS_DENIED" despite "OWNER" level access to the Storage Container
I've been working with Azure Video Indexer for a while now, and in addition to feeling super fragile, has now recently started (through no decernable action on my behalf) rejecting every upload request stating that it doesn't have access to the storage blob.
I can validate and confirm all the tokens coming back from azure management to then create a contributor token which is then used in the request and they look fine.
Testing on the web portal has the same issue: 
Full Error Message when trying to upload via the api:
{
    "ErrorType": "STORAGE_ACCESS_DENIED",
    "Message": "Storage account 'MYSTORAGENAMEHERE' can't be reached. System-assigned managed identity has insufficent permissions to the storage account. Make sure it has at least 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' permissions. Trace id: '4b213fc5-df2c-49fc-8f45-5c5a162c8b4f'."
}

however, If i now go to the azure portal and to the storage item it's clearly configured (in my angst I gave everyone and everything owner and contributor permissions and that didn't help either. That includes myself as a user in the event it's trying to use my token or something?) Anyway everyone has access, so I can't for the life of me understand the error?

Additionally, it feels like it is working, and there's a bug on their end, as for some reason the containers attached always end up with this file / blob created after failing an upload. to be clear this is not me adding that container of test file, so where is it coming from?

I don't understand the problem, it started happening randomly and i can't identify where or how. I've confirmed the storage bucket is accessible.
Other things that may be relevant.

The service is injected and uses new DefaultAzureCredential()
I'm logged in and authenticated to the Visual Studio / Azure services
This happened once before but only once and then not again since now


same issue here - nobody touched that service or the Azure portal, worked fine till today and suddenly this error. Any luck so far?

I logged a ticket and they acted all surprised when they replicated the bug. Appeared to be an outage but i can't find any logs or health / status updates. Guess they're just sweeping it under the rug?

Seems likely - our stuff just started working again
